# inheritance c# (youtube api)

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, youtube-api

New to c# and .net 
 I want to create declare properties in the Video_details class, I then want to populate them with data from the video_page class and then pass them onto the Video_upload class where the data is used, could someone recommend ow I would this, normally use java
( I amm creating a website where you upload videos to youtube using youtube data api)

Video_details:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Video_details
/// </summary>
public class Video_details
{
public Video_details()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}

public string vidTitle { get; set; }
public string vidDesc { get; set; }
public string vidTags { get; set; }    

}
```

Video_page method code:

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Video_details vidDetails = new Video_details();


    //get details from textBoxes
    txtTitle.Text = vidDetails.vidTitle.ToString();
    txtDesc.Text = vidDetails.vidDesc.ToString();
    txtTags.Text = vidDetails.vidTags.ToString();





    //lblUploadStatus.Text = "Upload Starting";
    Video_Upload uploadVideo = new Video_Upload();
    new Video_Upload().Run().Wait();
  //  lblVidTitle.Text = "Upload Successful...fat chance thats true";


}
```

Video_Upload method code:

```
 //VIDEO INFO AND DETAILS

    var video = new Video();
    video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    video.Snippet.Title = Video_details.vidTitle.ToString();
    video.Snippet.Description = "Testing Video Upload";
    video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "Test", "Second" };
    video.Snippet.CategoryId = "17";//category id for sport 
    video.Snippet.ChannelId = "UCfvR-wqeoHmAGrHnoQRfs9w";
    video.Status = new VideoStatus();
    video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public"; // or "private" or "public"
    var filePath = @"C:\Users\siobhan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\FYP_November\IMG_6638.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.
```

Comment: The first recommend that try to use C# convention. I saw google write a tut quite detail here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet

Comment: Ive used that, upload is working fine hardcoded, but want to get info from textboxes to pass over to method to use for upload

Comment: Not use some textboxs to passing data, you just create a constructor for Video_Upload class with Parameter is a object of Video_details. Or you can pass Parameter for Run function. Either new Video_Upload(vidDetails).Run().Wait(); or Video_Upload().Run(vidDetails).Wait();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to do the things the wrong way round. In `View_page` you must fill the properties of the `Video_details` from the text boxes:

```
vidDetails.vidTitle = txtTitle.Text;
...
```

Then the `Video_Upload` class must have some `Upload` method accepting a parameter of type `Video_details`

```
public class Video_upload
{
    public void Upload(Video_details video)
    {
        //TODO: upload the data here
    }
}
```

With this class you can then upload like this

```
uploadVideo.Upload(vidDetails);
```

---

For asynchronous uploads, have a look at [Asynchronous Programming with async and await (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) on MSDN.